# Error: cannot convert char (*)[] to char**' in initialization

Tags: c++, pointers, char

I am writing a program in which I keep getting an error. This program reads data from two txt files and print them out after sorting them. I have problem when I try to use a pointer to pointer to read a char array as follows:

```
int c;
cin >> c;

char** commands =  new char[c][256];  //first array read one complete line, and the second one read the array(data) of the lines

for(int i = 0; i <= c - 1; i++){
    cin >> commands[i];}
```

Can anyone please tell me where I am doing wrong? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: The declaration of `commands` must be `char (*commands)[256] = ...`.  it's a pointer to a line of 256 chars. You have `c` of those lines. Incrementing that pointer advances it by 256 bytes, i.e. to the next line, which is probably desired. As you can already guess, writing 256 literally is a terrible idea. Almost as terrible is to use raw pointers and allocations at all.

Answer (score 2):

A two-dimensional array (a matrix) is not an array of pointers.

The expression `new char[c][256]` allocates a two-dimensional array, an array of `c` one-dimensional arrays each of size 256. The result is a pointer to the first such item, i.e. a `char(*)[256]`.

In contrast, the pointer variable you try to initialize is of  type `char**`, which is a pointer to a pointer to `char`. Usually this is a pointer to the first item in array of pointers to `char`. That structure does not match what you allocated.

---

A two-dimensional array is called a **matrix**.

In the context of C and C++ raw arrays this term implies, by default, an array of arrays.

An array of pointers to arrays is called a **jagged array**, because it can have (pointers to) arrays of different sizes. E.g., a math matrix whose values are symmetric around the diagonal can be stored in arrays of sizes 1, 2, 3 and so on. In some cases jagged arrays are also used to implement square math matrices.

---

A good solution is to instead of raw arrays, use a `vector` of `string`:

```
vector<string> commands;
```

This way you don't even have to specify a size up front.

And the user doesn't have to specify a size, you can just `push_back` each new command.

Here `vector` is `std::vector` from the `<vector>` header, and `string` is `std::string` from the `<string>` header.

For reading commands you can then use `std:.getline`, also from the `<string>` header, which avoids reading only one whitespace-separated “word” at a time: it reads a whole line at a time.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am trying to avoid using vector according to the instructions of the program. If I want to use string what would be a good solution? Thank you again.

Comment: Well, if your teacher disallows use of standard library containers and smart pointers, then you can implement a simple string class that provides only what you use.

Comment: Thank you for your help! I think it is a good idea to go for.

Comment: I like Alf's comment to write your own string class a lot. If I were a teacher I'd give maximum points for that! Splendid and fun way to wiggle out (legitimately!) of a boring footwork assignment.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
int c;
std::cin >> c;

typedef char CmdBufType[256];

CmdBufType* commands = new char[c][256];

for(int i = 0; i < c; ++i)
{
    std::cin >> commands[i];
}
```

Notes:

1. You can also write `new CmdBufType[c];` This is the same as `new char[c][256];`
2. Better write `i < c` instead of `i <= c - 1`
3. Prefer a prefix operator (`++i`) instead of a postfix operator (`i++`). In a simple case like this one this does not matter much because the non-incremented value is not used and the compiler will optimize it away. But if `i` is an object, say an iterator, then it does matter.